# Windows universal app section data

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

First off apologies if this has been asked previously - feel free to point me in the right direction if it has.

I'm trying to write a Universal Hub App for Windows 8 & Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio (2013 Community edition if that makes a difference) and there's a specific part of the source code I can't change/alter and to be honest it's driving me around the twist.

Here's a screenshot of the part I can't change:

http://postimg.org/image/aoooaid99/

In between the two pictures of the Super Mario Land box art you'll see a section called "Categories". Under that there's six sections with various grey boxes, the title "Item Title:" and then "Nintendo". I've managed to change the text so it now shows "Nintendo" but I've only changed that once and I'd like each one to be unique and to link to a unique page - one for Nintendo, Sega, NEC etc... Any ideas?

The same applies to the "Item Title" text - that I can't find anywhere. Well, that's not entirely true. There's a file called data.js that *seems* to contain this information but changing it doesn't seem to make much difference. I also want to change the grey images for some other images I've already prepared (logos). Again this isn't obvious to a novice Visual Studio user like me.

I'm more than happy to plough through some documentation or follow a tutorial if any one knows of a good one online somewhere.

All help appreciated. I can post the source code if that would help but regarding this particular part of the code I haven't changed much.

Here's the code I changed to get the "Nintendo" to appear - from a file called data.js:

```
function generateSampleData() {
    var itemContent = "<p>Curabitur class aliquam vestibulum nam curae maecenas sed integer cras phasellus suspendisse quisque donec dis praesent accumsan bibendum pellentesque condimentum adipiscing etiam consequat vivamus dictumst aliquam duis convallis...;
    var itemDescription = "Item Description: Pellentesque porta mauris quis interdum vehicula urna sapien ultrices velit nec venenatis dui odio in augue cras posuere enim a cursus convallis neque turpis malesuada erat ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat";
    var groupDescription = "Group Description: Nintendo";
```

Comment: It's better to show the code where you changed it. It looks like you have changed the template in XAML. Which is the same for all items.

Comment: It looks like a template for items. Change the items data or create your own function to generate items (like generateSampleData()).

Answer (score 0):

If you press Ctrl+Shift+F ("find in files") and search for "Section 4", you'll find the text is likely declared in a .resjson file, e.g.:

```
"Section4": "Section 4",
"Section4Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ising elit, sed diam nonummy nibh uismod tincidunt ut laoreet suscipit lobortis nisl ut wisi quipexerci quis consequat minim veniam, quis nostrud. exerci tation ullam corper.",
```

When you change the "Section 4" to another text, it will update the UI.
Hope this helps!